# HTML code conversion to PDF concern

Tags: html, pdf, html5-canvas, html-to-pdf

This is more of a generic doubt rather than a code specific issue.

Suppose I have an HTML template that I want to convert to a PDF, only when a button -  "Export PDF" is clicked. The template is hidden as I don't want the users to see it, at any point. I have used "*display:none;*" to hide the HTML.

When a user click the button, the template is made visible and the data binding takes place. As required, the PDF is populated. I also have a canvas which is used render the HTML into the PDF. Everything works okay.

**Now, my doubt**:

> Is there any way that I can export the PDF without setting "*display: block;*"?

I know that a hidden HTML cannot be rendered into a canvas for PDF conversion. Or is there a way?

Due to a slight delay in the saving functionalities to run, the HTML template will be visible to the user. I don't want that to happen. What do I do?

Comment: Simply position it outside of the viewport …?

Comment: That may not work. Because the canvas may render a blank PDF when I take it out of the viewport